# Stopping Docker containers by image name - Ubuntu

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-image

On Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty Tahr) I'm looking for a way to stop a running container and the only information I have is the image name that was used in the Docker run command.

Is there a command to find all the matching running containers that match that image name and stop them?

Answer (score 342, accepted):

### If you know the `image:tag` exact container version

Following [issue 8959](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/8959), a good start would be:

```
docker ps -a -q --filter="name=<containerName>"
```

Since `name` refers to the *container* and not the image name, you would need to use the more recent [Docker 1.9 filter ancestor](https://github.com/docker/docker/commit/b1cb1b1df493b3e0b739b9f374b6c82e306dede8), mentioned in [koekiebox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/158288/koekiebox)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34899613/6309).

```
docker ps -a -q  --filter ancestor=<image-name>
```

---

As commented below by [kiril](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1919237/kiril), to remove those containers:

> `stop` returns the containers as well.

So chaining `stop` and `rm` will do the job:

```
docker rm $(docker stop $(docker ps -a -q --filter ancestor=<image-name> --format="{{.ID}}"))
```

---

### If you know only the image name (not `image:tag`)

As [Alex Jansen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/986696/alex-jansen) points out in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32073971/stopping-docker-containers-by-image-name-ubuntu/32074098#comment121207874_32074098):

> The [ancestor option](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/#filtering) does not support wildcard matching.

Alex [proposes a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68584752/6309), but the one I managed to run, when you have *multiple* containers running from the same image is (in your `~/.bashrc` for instance):

```
dsi() { docker stop $(docker ps -a | awk -v i="^$1.*" '{if($2~i){print$1}}'); }
```

Then I just call in my bash session (after sourcing `~/.bashrc`):

```
dsi alpine
```

And any container running from `alpine.*:xxx` would stop.

Meaning: any image whose name is *starting* with `alpine`.
You might need to tweak the `awk -v i="^$1.*"` if you want `^$1.*` to be more precise.

From there, of course:

```
drmi() { docker rm $(dsi $1  | tr '\n' ' '); }
```

And a `drmi alpine` would stop *and remove* any `alpine:xxx` container.

Comment: This is great. My problem after that is when removing the containers, since they are sttoped, they are not returned by docker pd. Any clues of how to do it?

Comment: @kiril stopped container are returned by `ps -a`. *Removed* containers... well they are removed, they do not exist anymore.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize stop returns the containers as well. So chaining stop and rm will do the job: docker rm $(docker stop $(docker ps -a -q --filter="name=<imageName>"))

Comment: @kiril That is the idea, yes.

Comment: This does not work if you only know the repository (ie: `my_image`) and not the specific image tag (ie: `my_image:some_specific_tag`).  The ancestor option does not support wildcard matching.

Comment: @AlexJansen Interesting feedback, thank you. I did not manage to make your solution work when  I have multiple container running from the same image, so I referenced your solution in my answer, and added my own implementation, based on yours. Again, thank you.

Comment: Looks good.  Turning it into a function seems like an improvement as well.

Comment: @AlexJansen Yes, I am way too lazy to remember all those commands ;)

Answer (score 115):

The previous answers did not work for me, but this did:

```
docker stop $(docker ps -q --filter ancestor=<image-name> )
```

Comment: Interesting use of ancestor there (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/#filtering). +1

Comment: Works on Docker Terminal for Windows as well.

Comment: This does not work for me in Ubuntu 20.04 with Docker version 20.10.5, build 55c4c88. the command `docker ps -q --filter ancestor=<image-name>` returns nothing, while the command `docker ps -a -q --filter ancestor=<image-name>` from the accepted answer returns the containers ids that are matching.

Comment: This answer also doesn't work if you only know the repository (ie: `my_image`) and not the specific image tag (ie: `my_image:some_specific_tag`). The ancestor option does not support wildcard matching.

Comment: add `-a` option  to remove all containers including stopped ones

Answer (score 73):

You could start the container setting a container name:

```
docker run -d --name <container-name> <image-name>
```

The same image could be used to spin up multiple containers, so this is a good way to start a container. Then you could use this container-name to stop, attach... the container:

```
docker exec -it <container-name> bash
docker stop <container-name>
docker rm <container-name>
```

Comment: I really like this solution. Is there a better way to build, stop/remove and then run a container than this?
`sudo docker build . -t <img-name> && sudo docker stop <container-name> || true && sudo docker run -d --rm --name <container-name> <img-name>`

Answer (score 24):

This code will stop **all** containers with the image **centos:6**. I couldn't find an easier solution for that.

```
docker ps | grep centos:6 | awk '{print $1}' | xargs docker stop
```

Or even shorter:

```
docker stop $(docker ps -a | grep centos:6 | awk '{print $1}')
```

Comment: need improvement ::::  docker stop $(docker ps -a  | grep centos:6 | awk '{print $1}')

Comment: @Shaileshkumar Added your version =)

Comment: Again, this requires that the tag be known.  I don't see any easy solution if you want to, for instance, stop all `centos` containers of any version.

Answer (score 9):

Two ways to stop running a container:

```
1. $docker stop container_ID

2. $docker kill container_ID
```

You can get running containers using the following command:

```
$docker ps
```

Following links for more information:

- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stop/
- https://docs.docker.com/v1.8/reference/commandline/kill/

Comment: The last link is broken (*"Sorry, we can't find that page"*).

Comment: Is it literally `$docker`? Or is `$` from the shell prompt?

Comment: This doesn't answer the post's initial question, "stopping a container by its image_name"

Answer (score 9):

This will **only stop** all containers with image = "yourImgName" :

```
sudo docker stop $(sudo docker ps | grep "yourImgName" | cut -d " " -f 1)
```

This will **stop and remove** all containers with image = "yourImgName" :

```
sudo docker rm $(sudo docker stop $(sudo docker ps -a | grep "yourImgName" | cut -d " " -f 1))
```

Answer (score 6):

I made a `/usr/local/bin/docker.stop` that takes in the image name (assumes you only have one running).

```
docker stop $(docker ps -q -f "name=$1")
```

Answer (score 4):

**Stop docker container by image name:**

```
imagename='mydockerimage'
docker stop $(docker ps | awk '{split($2,image,":"); print $1, image[1]}' | awk -v image=$imagename '$2 == image {print $1}')
```

**Stop docker container by image name and tag:**

```
imagename='mydockerimage:latest'
docker stop $(docker ps | awk -v image=$imagename '$2 == image {print $1}')
```

---

If you created the image, you can add a [label](https://docs.docker.com/config/labels-custom-metadata/) to it and filter running containers by label

```
docker ps -q --filter "label=image=$image"
```

---

**Unreliable methods**

```
docker ps -a -q  --filter ancestor=<image-name>
```

[does not always work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37255264/why-does-docker-filter-ancestor-imagename-find-the-wrong-container)

```
docker ps -a -q --filter="name=<containerName>"
```

filters by container name, not image name

```
docker ps | grep <image-name> | awk '{print $1}'
```

is problematic since the image name may appear in other columns for other images

Comment: This is the first answer here which actually supports stopping containers based on the image name.  The other answers require you to know the image tag as well.

Answer (score 3):

For Docker version 18.09.0
I found that format flag won't be needed

```
docker rm $(docker stop $(docker ps -a -q -f ancestor=<image-name>))
```

Answer (score 3):

list all containers with info and ID

```
docker ps

docker stop CONTAINER ID
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding on top of @VonC superb answer, here is a ZSH function that you can add into your .zshrc file:

```
dockstop() {
  docker rm $(docker stop $(docker ps -a -q --filter ancestor="$1" --format="{{.ID}}"))
}
```

Then in your command line, simply do `dockstop myImageName` and it will stop and remove all containers that were started from an image called myImageName.

Comment: dk() {  docker kill $(docker ps -q --filter ancestor="$1" --format="{{.ID}}"); }

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to wrap my Docker commands in gulp tasks and realised that you can do the following:

```
docker stop container-name
docker rm container-name
```

This might not work for scenarios where you have multiple containers with the same name (if that's possible), but for my use case it was perfect.

Answer (score 1):

In my case `--filter ancestor=<image-name>` was not working, so the following command cleaned up the Docker container for me:

```
docker rm $(docker stop $(docker ps -a -q --filter "name=container_name_here" --format="{{.ID}}"))
```

Answer (score 1):

use: **docker container stop $(docker container ls -q --filter ancestor=mongo)**

```
    (base) :~ user$ docker ps
    CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                      NAMES
    d394144acf3a        mongo               "docker-entrypoint.s…"   15 seconds ago      Up 14 seconds       0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp   magical_nobel
    (base) :~ user$ docker container stop $(docker container ls -q --filter ancestor=mongo)
    d394144acf3a
    (base) :~ user$ docker ps
    CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
    (base) :~ user$
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my script to rebuild docker container, stop and start it again

```sh
docker pull [registry]/[image]:latest
docker build --no-cache -t [localregistry]/[localimagename]:latest -f compose.yaml context/
docker ps --no-trunc | grep [localimagename] | awk '{print $1}' | xargs docker stop
docker run -d -p 8111:80 [localregistry]/[localimagename]:latest
```

note --no-trunc argument which shows the image name or other info in full lenght in the output

Answer (score 1):

Here's a concise command which doesn't require you to specify the image tag (as most of these answers do):

`docker stop $(docker ps -a | awk -v i="^${image_name}.*" '{if($2~i){print$1}}')`

Comment: Are you sure about those double quotes in `docker stop "$(...)"`? Whenever I try your option, I get: `Error response from daemon: No such container: 804d82eebf40 36adf6b2be3d d288a5f934dd`. Without the double quotes though, it does work.

Comment: It does look like the double-quotes were a mistake.  I just tested without them and now it works.  It doesn't look like I needed the `tr` call either.  Do you remember the specific situation where it was needed?

Comment: What I do for testing is a bunch of `docker run -d alpine:3.10.3 tail -f /dev/null`. Then I try to stop them all in one go.

Comment: Do you mean images or containers?  I tested with multiple containers from the same image and was able to stop them all at once.  I imagine you'd have to run the command multiple times for multiple images.

Comment: Got it: my version used `print $1` instead of `print$1`: with `print$1`, no need for `tr`. Thank you again. I will fix my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
docker stop $(docker ps -a | grep "zalenium")
docker rm $(docker ps -a | grep "zalenium")
```

This should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prefer a simple `AWK` approach, here Is my take:

```
docker rm -f $(docker ps | awk '{ if($2 == "<your image name>") { print $NF}}')
```

`$(docker ps | awk '{ if($2 == "<your image name>") { print $NF}}')` - prints the docker container names based on input image

`docker ps` - list all containers

`awk '{ if($2 == "<your-image-name>") { print $NF}}'` - The second parsed column of `docker ps` gives the image name. Comparing it with your image name will execute `print $NF` which prints the container name.

`docker rm -f` removes the containers

For example, removing all running containers of ubuntu image, can be done simply as:

```
docker rm -f $(docker ps | awk '{ if($2 == "ubuntu:latest") { print $NF}}')
```

PS: Remember to include the image tag in AWK, since it's a equal comparator.

Answer (score 0):

if you know a part of the container name you can use AWK with docker as following :

```
  CONTAINER_IDS=$(docker ps -a | awk '($2 ~ /container.*/) {print $1}')
  if [ -z "$CONTAINER_IDS" -o "$CONTAINER_IDS" == " " ]; then
    echo "No containers available for deletion"
  else
    docker rm -f $CONTAINER_IDS
  fi
```

Answer (score 0):

```
image: docker
services:
  - docker:dind
stages:
  - deploy
step-deploy-prod:
  stage: deploy
  tags:
  - docker
  script:
    - container_id=$(docker ps -q -a -f status=running --filter name=todoapp)
    - if [ -n "$container_id" ]; then 
        docker stop $container_id; 
        docker rm -f $container_id;
      fi
    - container_id=$(docker ps -q -a -f status=exited --filter name=todoapp)
    - if [ -n "$container_id" ]; then 
        docker rm -f $container_id;
      fi
    - docker build -t app/creative .
    - docker run -d -p 8081:80 --name todoapp app/creative
```

First, check for a running container with the command `docker ps -q -a -f status=running --filter name=todoapp` , if it finds one it stops and deletes the running container then check for any containers that are stopped and have the name `todoapp` using the command `docker ps -q -a -f status=exited --filter name=todoapp`, then it will remove the container if it's found.
Then it will build a new image and start a new container with the new build image.

As I have found out, if you stop the container, it can't be found with `docker rm` just incase anyone stumbles across this if you are wanting to replace a newly deployed image via gitlab-ci

There is an option in `docker ps` command `-f status=exited` which shows all the containers which are in stopped state.

```
container_id=$(docker ps -q -a -f status=exited --filter name=todoapp)
```

This command would only return container ids that are stopped and has name todoapp

Also, a better way to remove the stopped container is by using the `-f` or `--force` option with the `docker rm` command. This option will remove the container even if it is in a stopped state.

Answer (score -4):

You can use the `ps` command to take a look at the running containers:

```
docker ps -a
```

From there you should see the name of your container along with the container ID that you're looking for. [Here's more information about `docker ps`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/ps/).

Comment: The link is broken (*Sorry, we can't find that page*).