# Stopping docker containers by image name, and don't error if no containers are running

Tags: bash, docker

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32073971/stopping-docker-containers-by-image-name-ubuntu) explains how to stop Docker containers started from an image.

But if there are no running containers I get the error **docker stop requires a minimum of one argument**. Which means I can't run this command in a long .sh script without it breaking.

How do I change these commands to work even if no results are found?

```
docker stop $(docker ps -q --filter ancestor="imagname")
docker rm `docker ps -aq` &&
```

*(I'm looking for a pure Docker answer if possible, not a bash test, as I'm running my script over ssh so I don't think I have access to normal script tests)*

Comment: Found the answer in kampde's comment on this blog post: http://blog.yohanliyanage.com/2015/05/docker-clean-up-after-yourself/. Just use xargs with r to ignore empty pipes: **docker ps -q --filter ancestor="imageName" | xargs -r docker stop**

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer and accept it.

Comment: **See Also**: [Stopping Docker containers by image name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32073971/1366033)

Answer (score 29):

Putting this in case we can help others:

To stop containers using specific image:

```
docker ps -q --filter ancestor="imagename" | xargs -r docker stop
```

To remove exited containers:

```
docker rm -v $(docker ps -a -q -f status=exited)
```

To remove unused images:

```
docker rmi $(docker images -f "dangling=true" -q)
```

If you are using a Docker > 1.9:

```
docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -qf dangling=true)
```

If you are using Docker <= 1.9, use this instead:

```
docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /var/lib/docker:/var/lib/docker --rm martin/docker-cleanup-volumes
```

**Docker 1.13 Update:**

To remove unused images:

```
docker image prune
```

To remove unused containers:

```
docker container prune
```

To remove unused volumes:

```
docker volume prune
```

To remove unused networks:

```
docker network prune
```

To remove all unused components:

```
docker system prune
```

IMPORTANT: Make sure you understand the commands and backup important data before executing this in production.

Comment: Trying how to figure out how to use this one on macos `docker ps -q --filter ancestor="imagename" | xargs -r docker stop` which reports `xargs: illegal option -- r
usage: xargs [-0opt] [-E eofstr] [-I replstr [-R replacements]] [-J replstr]
             [-L number] [-n number [-x]] [-P maxprocs] [-s size]
             [utility [argument ...]]`

Comment: OK, on mac I guess we can't protect ourselves from the empty strings so easily, just remove `-r` -> `docker ps -q --filter ancestor="web-container" | xargs docker stop`