# Stop docker containers with name matching a pattern

Tags: docker

I'm using [`puckel/docker-airflow`](https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow) with [`CeleryExecutor`](https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow/blob/master/docker-compose-CeleryExecutor.yml). It launches a total of 5 containers named like this

```
docker-airflow_flower_1_de2035f778e6
docker-airflow_redis_1_49d2e710e82b
..
```

---

While development, I often have to stop all above containers. However, I can't do a `docker stop $(docker ps -aq)` since I have other containers running on my machine too.

Is there a way to stop all containers who's names match a given pattern (for instance all containers who's names start with `docker-airflow` in above)?

Comment: **See Also**: [Stopping Docker containers by image name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32073971/1366033)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

From this article by [@james-coyle](https://www.jamescoyle.net/author/james-coyle), following command works for me

```
docker ps --filter name=docker-airflow* --filter status=running -aq | xargs docker stop
```

I believe `docker CLI` natively does not provide such a functionality, so we have to rely on filtering and good-old [`bash` PIPE and `xargs`](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-bsd-xargs-construct-argument-lists-utility/)

---

**UPDATE-1**

Note that depending on your environment, you might have to do these

- run docker commands with `sudo` (just prefix both `docker ..` commands above with `sudo`)
- enclose name pattern in double-quotes `--filter name="docker-airflow*"` (particularly on `zsh`)

Comment: This didn't work for me unless I added quotes around the search string, e.g. 

docker ps --filter name="docker-airflow*"

Answer (score 14):

Better late than never ;). From [this](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/docker-tip-83-stop-docker-containers-by-name-pattern) article. The following works for me:

**Stop containers with names matching a given pattern:**

```
$ docker container stop $(docker container ls -q --filter name=<pattern>)
```

On the other hand, if we want to start containers with names matching a given pattern:

```
$ docker container start $(docker container ls --all -q --filter name=<pattern>)
```

**NOTE:** For different environments related tips, @y2k-shubham's update is a good starting point.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach using `grep` and `docker ps`:

To stop docker container matching the given pattern/list of pattern":

```
docker ps | grep  -E "name_1|name_2|name_3"  |  awk '{print $1}' | xargs docker stop
```

To stop docker container excluding the given pattern/list of pattern:

```
docker ps | grep  -Ev "name_1|name_2|name_3" |  awk '{print $1}' | xargs docker stop
```

Reference: [Grep](https://web.archive.org/web/20220128165525/https://ryanstutorials.net/linuxtutorial/cheatsheetgrep.php)